# Add Items to a drop down list whose datasource is already set in a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a drop down list whose4 datasoruce is already set, I need to add an extra item, in webapplications it's easy, using Items.Insert(index, newItem). but in windows applications it is not working, any body can help!

Note: I need to add the items without affecting the datasource at all
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataSource doesn't have an Add method. You will have to either create your own DataSource (`List<...>`) or add item iteratively.

Comment: Thats the soltion I went with, creating my own datasource. It seems that after a combo box is databound, you can't add items unless you add them to the datasource it self

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is a dataset or list, try adding items to it and those will appear in the drop down.

Comment: The datasource I am using has no mthods of adding new items :S

Comment: ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Data.TableBindingAdapter, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/componenthelp/index.html#/d/0003000009tq000000.htm

Comment: If you look in the members of that class there is Add(object) method.

Comment: No supported on this TableBindgAdapter :S, a note written on the first line

Comment: Sorry, did not read the details. But I presume you are passing some RowCollction/Table to the constructor of that binding source. does that not allow Add method?